# Want to determine the safest site for a femoral arterial puncture

Tags: medicine

We collected the data form CT scans of 200 cases as follow:
The site of the bifurcation in relation to head of femur in each patient from (1-5) and according to the pubic tubercle (1-3).
The site of the inferior epigastric artery in relation to the in relation the head of the femur (1-5). 
Majority of the patient had the bifurcation below point 4 in relation to the head of the femur and epigastric artery branching above point 2, which is the common femoral artery course, so line of the least complication when punctured. 
[image]
So depending on the bony landmarks alone, can I statistically prove that it is safe to assume the course of the common femoral artery from these data?